# Spec for changed local.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, yaml, rspec-rails, ruby-1.9.3

I have a method that changes some local.yml variables. To test that method I had to stub those variables, but I also want to test if the local.yml was changed and what was written on it. Is it possible to do that, since I could only load the outdated file?

Answer (score 0):

Right before the method changes local.yml variables it could save the old local.yml variable & the new variable into another file.